# How to make Nginx alias return custom header on 404?

Tags: nginx

I'm using this to serve static file with nginx:

```
location /static/images {
  alias /root/story/static/images;
}
```

and cloudflare will cache the file for me

however, if the file is 404, cloudflare will also cache the 404, even if the file exists later.

so how can I make nginx return a 'no-cache' header, if the file is 404?

Answer (score 0):

With something like this:

```
location /static/images {
    ...
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        add_header Cache-Control 'no-cache';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To provide a fallback on file inexistence, you could use [`try_files`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) in combination with a named location.

Moreover, you will need to use the [`add_header`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) with the `always` flag set in order to insert the header in responses with status codes other than the specified list.

```
location /static/images {
    root /root/story;
    try_files $uri @notFound;
}

location @notFound {
    internal;
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache always;
}
```

Note: `root` is to be preferred to `alias` wherever possible, as the latter might result in an unwanted behavior, [conflicting with other directives such as `try_files`](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97).